# Add empty option on angularjs selectize dynamically

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I am trying to add dynamically an empty option to angularjs selectize https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize

I have my config on the controller

```
$scope.mySelectizeConfig = {
  persist: false,
  maxItems: 1,
  labelField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id',
  searchField: ['name'],
  placeholder: 'Choose Item',
  onInitialize: function(selectize) {
    $timeout(function() {
      selectize.addOption({id:'', name: 'None'});
    })
  }
};
```

This works in cases where there is nothing selected, when there are selected values it only shows the new option after I clear the search field.
I have tried 
`selectize.refreshOptions();`
but that breaks the plugin, it's been shown open and doesn't select the an item at all.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in which I could take a look at? (plnker, jsfiddle, codepen, or any other)

Comment: ok will try to do that.